# Solr, only returning results if EdgeNGramFilterFactory matches

Tags: solr

I'm searching a multivalued field which is defined as:

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" 
                side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But if I'm searching for words which are longer than the `maxGramSize` of 15, I don't get any results. So with the following indexed:

```
vedlikeholdsskjema på toyota corolla Gode ting  kiwi kan spises med skall, banan
```

I get results on "kiwi", "banan" etc. but not on "vedlikeholdsskjema". I guess I could increase the `maxGramSize` size, but I would have thought the `StandardTokenizerFactory` and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` would have given me matches in this case.

Here is screenshot of the analysis page [image: analysis].

I'm running Solr 4.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. In the above case you need to increase the maxGramSize more than 15 to get the desired result/output.

But before that do you really need a word to be splitted into multiple  words. I mean what is your search criteria? Do you want partial word search?

For example :
When a user searches with "vedlikeh" then you want him to show the results of "vedlikeholdsskjema". This is partial word search. If its the requirement then you should go on increasing  maxGramSize.

But I think if you don't have such requirement then there is not point in increasing the index size. You should rather go for simpler field type.
Either use the existing or create your own depending on your requirement.

For more info on the "EdgeNGramFilterFactory" please refer

https://abhijitbashetti.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=LXjm5UsBAAA.tsbzRwFnTyQES0DzsnH33w.tfM2TzT7I-W7O5LeYq7qvA&postId=6309840933546641223&type=POST

Comment: I'm still slightly confused as to why `StandardTokenizerFactory` and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` don't give me any results? They match in the analysis tool. We use `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` as we have an auto complete search. And we also expect to get results for "vedlikehold", "skjema" and "vedlikeholdsskjema" which are all valid norwegian words. But maybe there are better ways to accomplish that?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the analysis result. The result shows you 5 steps/tables from top to bottom. During the first tow steps you still have a match, afterwards you are loosing it. There is not highlighting in grey from step 3 onwards.

Comment: StandardTokenizerFactory and LowerCaseFilterFactory won't give you any results because after that you have added EdgeNGramFilterFactory.   And after EdgeNGramFilterFactory is not creating the correct index as per your expectation. You can check the final analysis where you dont see 'vedlikeholdsskjema'. Final analysis is after the "org.apache.solr.analysis.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" in Index analyser.  There is no index ...there wont be any search result...